# Does VS2019 or a similar program have *horizontal* rulers?

Tags: text-editors, text-formatting, visual-studio-2019

I've started using vertical rulers in VS2019 to help keep my lines from running longer than 80 columns. I've noticed that sometimes my functions start to run long as well, and was wondering: is there was a similar plugin that would warn me at, say, 25 lines after an indent? If not, does any text editor have this feature?

Comment: if you can't see `public String foo(String in){` and the matching `}// end foo(String in)` without scrolling, you've gone past your limit.  Simply adjust display to match your preferences....  on that note, I'm still looking for the endless display - a method/function has as much code as it needs in it, there is no magical line number limit.

Comment: There are indeed add-ons that will enforce syntax formatting rules.  However, questions seeking those specific add-ons, are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound, where should I ask? I wasn't sure where to bring this up -- it seems more like "asking for help using a tool" than it does "asking for software recommendations", but I guess it's a bit of both.